# where between in laravel are so literal

Tags: php, laravel, forms

if I has a function like this

```
if($request->has('q')){
    $q=$request->q;
    $from_price=$request->from_price;
    $to_price=$request->to_price;
    $products = Product::where('title','like','%'.$q.'%')
    ->whereBetween('price',[$from_price, $to_price])
    ->orderBy('id','desc')->Paginate(6);
}else{
    $products = Product::where('category_id',$cat_id)->orderBy('id','desc')->paginate(6);
}
```

where give me the title from input q
and also I used therebetween for price
but where between doesn't work except after I put 0 and exactly the product price
example:
I have iPhone 12 and it is 999$
I should write 0 and 999
and if I write 0 and 1000
it doesn't work

Comment: also I want this function to work if type in search only

Comment: your `price` column on your tale is not numeric? It should be a numeric format, ex : integer or decimal

Comment: can you write the code @sta

Comment: Your migration is something like ? `$table->string('price');` ?

Comment: Yes it is string

Comment: do you know how to make it numeric

Comment: @sta can you tell it is the final thing to finish in my project

Comment: change it to decimal `$table->decimal('price');` https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#column-method-decimal

Comment: it say `Property [whereBetween] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try below code

```
if($request->has('q')){
    $q=$request->q;
    $from_price=(float)$request->from_price;
    $to_price=(float)$request->to_price;
    $products = Product::where('title','like','%'.$q.'%')
    ->whereBetween('price',[$from_price, $to_price])
    ->orderBy('id','desc')->Paginate(6);
}else{
     $products = Product::where('category_id',$cat_id)->orderBy('id','desc')->paginate(6);
}
```

Comment: thank you it works succesfully can you explain what you did?

Comment: Just convert string to float which will required while using whereBetween

Comment: final thing if I wanted to search by category do it type this : `            $products = Product::where('title','like','%'.$q.'%')
            ->where('category_id','like','%'.$category.'%')
            ->whereBetween('price',[$from_price, $to_price])
            ->orderBy('id','desc')->Paginate(6);`

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your AppServiceProvider boot method:

```
        Builder::macro('whereLike', function ($attributes, string $searchTerm) {
        $this->where(function (Builder $query) use ($attributes, $searchTerm) {
            foreach (Arr::wrap($attributes) as $attribute) {
                $query->orWhere($attribute, 'LIKE', "%{$searchTerm}%");
            }
        });
        return $this;
    });
```

Then for your query you can use:

```
$products = Product::whereLike('title', $q)
->whereBetween('price',[$from_price, $to_price])
->orderBy('id','desc')
->Paginate(6);
```

Source:
https://freek.dev/1182-searching-models-using-a-where-like-query-in-laravel

Comment: Class 'App\Providers\Builder' not found

Comment: it say Class 'App\Providers\Builder' not found

Comment: Add this:
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
on top

Comment: Class 'App\Providers\Arr' not found

Comment: also if i let $q empty it say `Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::App\Providers\{closure}() must be of the type string, null given, called in C:\xamppx\htdocs\emart\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder.php on line 1642`

Comment: I would really suggest to learn importing classes in Laravel. Add this in beginning: use Illuminate\Support\Arr;

Comment: you should pass something to $q, it is null currently. Try dd before calling the query

Comment: so if I want to allow letting the q empty how I can do that as if filered price only I get error

Comment: what to  put as value ?

Comment: The query I added should be inside if($request->has('q')){..} not for all query

Comment: I don't know what to put as if I put like space it say same error @Sallin Rexha

Comment: `if($request->has('q')){
    $q=$request->q;
    $from_price=$request->from_price;
    $to_price=$request->to_price;
$products = Product::whereLike('title', $q)
->whereBetween('price',[$from_price, $to_price])
->orderBy('id','desc')
->Paginate(6);
}
else{
    $products = Product::where('category_id',$cat_id)->orderBy('id','desc')->paginate(6);
}`

Comment: it give error `TypeError
Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::App\Providers\{closure}() must be of the type string, null given, called in C:\xamppx\htdocs\emart\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder.php on line 1642`

Answer (score 0):

```
if($request->has('q')){
  $q=$request->q;
  $from_price=$request->from_price;
  $to_price=$request->to_price;
  $products = Product::whereLike('title', $q)
    ->whereBetween('price',[$from_price, $to_price])
    ->orderBy('id','desc')
    ->Paginate(6);
}
else {
  $products = Product::where('category_id',$cat_id)->orderBy('id','desc')->paginate(6);
    }
```